# Compare 2 arrays and remove matches

Tags: perl, array-splice

I have 2 arrays (`@system`,`@reserve`). Each contain a list of numbers and I'd like to compare and splice out (maybe?) the numbers in `@reserve` which match numbers in `@system`.

I've tried some of the responses to find and splice questions out there, but they don't seem to be working.  Using Perl 5.12.4.

Numbers in `@reserve` will always be 11000..136000 and the numbers in system will always be within the `@system` range but will vary.  The code that I've been focusing on looks like:

```
my @system = query();
my @reserve = 11000..136000;

foreach my $num (@system) {
my $index = 0;
$index++ until $reserve[$index] eq $num;
splice (@reserve,$index,1);
}
```

query() just asks the system (PBX) for a list of numbers and pushes them into `@system`.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Marty

Comment: Whilst this problem is better solved using the keys of a hash as a set, on a programming point your inner loop is potentially dicey in that it could hang if `$num` doesn't appear in `@reserve`. Also your values appear to be numbers, but you're comparing them using `eq`, the *string* equality operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to work with `splice` when you use a hashslice instead:

```
my @system = query();

my %reserve ;
@reserve{(11000..136000)} = undef ;

delete @reserve{@system} ;
my @list_of_reserve = sort { $a <=> $b } keys %reserve ;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
my @system = query();
my @reserve = 11000..136000;
my %tmp = map{$_ => 1}@system;
@reserve = grep{!exists $tmp{$_}}@reserve;
```